# OpenSuse 13.1 PPC64 Port - Slow boot with error messages, and low color-depth

Tags: linux, xorg, opensuse

I have a PowerMac G5 Dual 2.0 GHz, i have installed the PPC64 port of OpenSuse 13.1 on it, and i am experiencing a few problems. I guess thats the price of running a unsupported port/distribution.

**Hardware Summary**

- PowerMac G5 Dual 2.0Ghz PPC64
- RAM: 1GB DDR PC3200 (Soon to be upgraded to 8GB)
- Graphics: Nvidia GeForce FX5200 Ultra
- Harddisk: Western Digital SATA 150 160GB

**Boot**

The machine takes a long time to boot, and i get the following message:

```
prom_parse: Bad cell count for /pci@0,f0000000/NVDA, Parent@NVDA,Display-A@0
i2c i2c-6: Failed to register i2c client MAC,fcu at 0x2f (-16)
i2c i2c-6: i2c-powermac: Failure to register /u3@0,f8000000/i2c@f8001000/fan@15e
i2c 12c-6: i2c-powermac: modalias failure on /u3@0,f8000000/i2c@f8001000/cerea1@1c0
i2c 12c-7: Failed to register i2c client MAC,ds1775 at 0x4a (-16)
i2c 12c-7: i2c-powermac: Failure to register /u3@0,f8000000/i2c@80001000/temp-monitor@94
i2c 12c-7: Failed to register client MAC,max6690 at 0x4c (-16)
i2c 12c-7: i2c-powermac: Failure to register /u3@0,f8000000/i2c@80001000/temp-monitor@98
i2c 12c-7: Failed to register client MAC,ad7417 at 0x2c (-16)
i2c 12c-7: i2c-powermac: Failure to register /u3@0,f8000000/i2c@80001000/supply-monitor@58
i2c 12c-7: Failed to register client MAC,ad7417 at 0x2d (-16)
i2c 12c-7: i2c-powermac: Failure to register /u3@0,f8000000/i2c@80001000/supply-monitor@5a
/home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/kernel-default-3.11.6/linux-3.11/drivers/rtc/hctosys.c: unable to open rtc device (rtc0)
SysRq : Changing Loglevel
Loglevel set to 1
```

But after a minute or two, the boot process is continued, and i eventually get to the KDE login screen, everything works after login, although a little slow and unstable.

- Here is what dmesg returns: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=iKx2ZvCh
- Here is what lspci, hwinfo and lscpu returns: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=5TGLtFEa

**Graphics**

The noveau driver is being used by X11, and i am unable to get more than 16bit color on the monitor, the resolution is right though, at 1920x1200 but i would like to get 24bit color, i
i have tried setting the color depth from KDE and Yast2, but there is no place where i am able to specify the color depth. Under Configure Desktop -> Display and Monitor there is no option to set the resolution or color depth. I know the FX5200 and the monitor both support 32bit color.

I have generated a xorg.conf file using the following procedure:

1. Go to runlevel 3 using the command "init 3" from the console.
2. Execute Xorg -configure.
3. Move the generated xorg.conf.new to /etc/X11/xorg.conf.
4. Edited the screen section and changed the color depth from 16bit to 24 bit.
5. Restarted using the command "reboot"

But it had no effect.

**What i want**

- An acceptable boot time (2-3min)
- No error messages at boot
- A stable system
- 24 or 32bit color

If someone would help me eliminate some of these isues, it would be great.